# How to derive time complexity of following method.

Tags: computational-complexity, time-series

I have one algorithm for which I have to find time complexity of number of time x=x+1 is executed:

```
j=n;
while(j>=1){
  for i=1 to j
    x =x+1
  j=j/2
}
```

What I am doing is : while loop will run for logN times and so as for loop.

That's why T(n) = (logN) * (logN)

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first iteration of the `while` loop, notice that $j$ is still equal to $n$, and therefore the `for` loop will execute $n$ times.
That is, we already have executed `x=x+1` $n$ times.
For large $n$, we find that $n > (\log n)^2,$ so unfortunately right away we know
the time complexity cannot be $(\log n)\cdot(\log n).$

Sometimes it's better to just count the innermost loop.
In this case the first time the `for` loop runs, it iterates $n$ times.
The next time the  `for` loop starts, it iterates $n/2$ times (rounded down),
the time after that iterates $n/4$ times (rounded down),
and so forth until the last time through, when it iterates just once (because $j=1$).

So to find the number of times we execute `x=x+1` altogether, just add up
the iterations for each time the `for` loop starts. These are at most:

$$n + \frac n2 + \frac n4 + \frac n8 + \ldots + 1.$$

The exact answer will be a little less when $n$ is not a power of $2,$ but not
too much less. It is easy to add up this total and to find its asymptotic form.